# Sequelize query table by column and associated record's column

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js

I am trying to query for music albums that are associated with an exact amount of artists.

I am correctly associating the models using a many-to-many table but my query is failing to do what I'd like it to do.

```
    albumArtists = albumArtists.map((artist) => {
        return artist.id;
    });

   const album = await DB.Album.findOne({
        where: {
            name: albumName,
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: DB.Artist,
                through: {
                    where: {
                        artistId: {
                            [Op.and]: albumArtists
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        ],
    });
```

I am trying to query for an album with `name` set to `albumName` and has associated `albumArtists` with `artistId` matching all in `albumArtists`.

I tried setting my `where` clause outside of the `through` object but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update through to this one:

```
through: { model: DB.AlbumArtists // write correct model name }
```

And also yo can simplify where condition:

```
where: { artistId: albumArtists }
```